# In Chrome undo does not work properly for input element after contents changed programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, input, undo, undo-redo

In Chrome, I noticed that undo does not work properly for input element after the contents of the element has been changed programmatically. Although I get different behaviours for different browsers, they're not as bad as Chrome.

```
FF20      good
IE9       some support (undo stack cleared when input loses focus)
Safari5   some support (undo stack cleared when input loses focus)
Chrome26  unreliable
```

For example, a script that trims spaces (see also jsfiddle below)

- type some spaces before "hello!",
- click outside the input element
- click on the input element and press Ctrl-Z

now the text is gone (in Chome)

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/K75t7/)

```
<input type="text" id="input1" value="hello!">

document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener('blur', function(evt){elementLosesFocus(evt, this);}, false);

function elementLosesFocus(evt, caller)
{
    caller.value = caller.value.trim();
}
```

I think the best thing I can hope for is a method to somehow clear the undo history of the input when it loses focus (as is the case with IE and Safari).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome doesn't store the field's states, but rather a diff or set of deltas for each undo/redo. It takes less memory, but causes the bug you're dealing with.

You can effectively simulate the user pasting a value into the field by using `document.execCommand("insertText", false, "text to insert");`.

For your particular case:

1. First, save the field's value to a variable. `var temp = caller.value;`
2. Next, clear the field's value or set its selectionStart to 0 and selectionEnd to the field's length. This way a simulated paste replaces the field's contents.
3. Next, make sure the field has the focus. `caller.focus();`
4. Finally, simulate the user pasting in the modified value. `document.execCommand("insertText", false, temp.trim());`

I found this solution in another SO question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10345596/1021426

Comment: This is gold. Thank you! There are tons of libraries that handle carets, selections and replacing them but all of them use `input.value` or `textarea.text` in the end which lead to the undo-problems the OP described.

Comment: Just note the it will NOT work in Firefox. If `document.execCommand` returns false then you need to fallback to setting value directly (not by pasting text). See bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220696

Comment: [document.execCommand() is deprecated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand)