# How to enable Ctrl + Z when you change an input text dynamically with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple [React markdown editor](https://github.com/andrerpena/react-mde).

[image: editor]

The component is completely controlled. The problem is: If the user selects `abc` in the textarea and clicks the **B** button, I need to call `onchange()` with `**abc**`. I need to surround the text with these asterisks.

This difference between what I pass on the `onchange()` and what the user has actually typed causes the textarea history to become inconsistent. Ctrl + Z doesn't work anymore.

[Demo](https://andrerpena.github.io/react-mde/). [EDIT: This demo has the fix implemented. It's not as it was when I asked the question]

How can I trigger `onchange()` on React with an arbitrary text and keep the Ctrl  + Z consistent?

Comment: There's [a discussion around undo/redo stack](https://github.com/w3c/editing/issues/150) which gives a bit of insight into how your case might be implemented. The idea would be to suppress default Cmd+Z or Ctrl+Z behavior and implement a custom input change history.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin, thanks for the link. That's frustrating but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

I didn't solve the problem but it's possibly the best I can do to without re-implementing history as @Rishat mentioned (If I'm mistaken, please let me know).

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27028331/192729), I got to understand this command:

```
document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
```

This basically inserts `text` in the currently focused input in the current caret position (that's why you don't pass the input as a parameter). And, of course, this function updates the history accordingly.

If I wanted, I could coordinate every insert (like the `**` mentioned in the question) in such a way that everything would be in the history.  However, that would be too complicated because each markdown command has a different behavior. It would be too laborious.

**Solution:**

The following code has to be on `componentDidUpdate`, and should only be executed **after the text is changed programatically**:

```
// In order to minimize the history problem with inputs, we're doing some tricks:
//  - Set focus on the textarea
//  - Set the value back to its previous value.
//  - Select the whole text (that's the problem)
//  - Insert the new value
this.refs.textarea.focus();
this.refs.textarea.value = previousText;
setSelection(this.refs.textarea, 0, previousText.length);
document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
```

**Effect**

The Ctrl + Z works perfectly, but if you keep going back until the time the input was changed programatically, it will select the whole text. I mean, the history is preserved but at the cost of messing up with the selection if you go back enough. I believe it's good enough, better than re-implementing the input history.

[Demo](https://andrerpena.github.io/react-mde/).