# Is it possible to insert text in textarea and update undo/redo queue?

Tags: javascript, textarea, undo-redo

A few days ago, I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708836/replace-text-in-textarea-using-textinput-event) regarding how to update text in Internet Explorer. As it appears, the method used doesn't also works in Firefox.

This made me thinks if there is a way to modify the value of a textarea and update the undo/redo queue as well (calling `ctrl-Z` or `document.execCommand('undo');`)

So far, I have found two possibilities, but they don't work in all the browsers :

Option 1:

```
var event = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
event.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, null, text, 9, "en-US");
textarea.focus();
textarea[0].setSelectionRange(selection.start, selection.end);
textarea[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

Note: Doesn't seems to work in IE (at all) and Firefox

Option 2 :

```
document.execCommand("insertText", false, "the text to insert");
```

Doesn't work in IE (tested under 9, but seems to not be implemented at all), I don't know for the others browsers.

Comment: this is not implemented in IE including IE11, which is quite frustrating! It works in Edge though.

Answer (score 7):

The solution I come up so far is this one, but I'm open for betters ideas :

I check for the existence of the insertText via document.queryCommandSupported. If it does exists, I use it. If not, I simply replace the text :

```
var text = "hello world",
    textarea = jQuery("textarea"),
    selection = {'start': textarea[0].selectionStart, 'end': textarea[0].selectionEnd};

if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
}
else {
    textarea.val(textarea.val().substring(0, selection.start) + text + textarea.val().substring(selection.end, textarea.val().length));
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for this too, and `insertText` works, but still somehow messes up the undo/redo history a bit. See http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/k4spa0dv/ After undoing and redoing a few programmatic changes, it loses the last few history items, so redo won't redo everything... Any idea? (Chrome btw)

Comment: document.execCommand returns true if the command was executed successfully, i used the return value instead of checking queryCommandSupported first. Also don't forget to update the carret position using `.setSelectionRange(start,end)` after you changed the value without execCommand.

Comment: Note! This does not work for Firefox! `insertText` command is supported but only for `contenteditable` elements. Not for textarea.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 works well as of now (8/19/2016), but is deprecated in Chrome for one of the upcoming releases. Dispatching the event generates the following warning:

> A DOM event generated from JavaScript has triggered a default action inside the browser. This behavior is non-standard and will be removed in M53, around September 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832 for more details.

Comment: Great!.. one step forward two steps back. :p

Comment: Seems `dispatchEvent` is widely available now: https://caniuse.com/?search=dispatchEvent

Answer (score 0):

It seems that as of today, all modern browsers support your option #1, dispatchEvent. See more here:

http://help.dottoro.com/ljrinokx.php

Comment: Still has messed up history (Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/k4spa0dv/ After undoing and redoing a few times, he's totally confused and redo/undo history is lost. Firefox doesn't work at all.

Comment: It seems there's still no cross-browser solution for this. At least IE doesn't work properly with any of the proposed methods in the jsfiddle. What a shame.

Answer (score 0):

Only browsers that support `document.execCommand("insertText")` have `undo` support (at the moment: Chrome, Safari, Opera). Other browsers have various ways to insert text but no `undo` support.

Try [insert-text-textarea](https://github.com/bfred-it/insert-text-textarea) to wrap some of the solutions on this page for modern browser support. If you need IE8+ support, try the [insert-text-at-cursor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/insert-text-at-cursor) package.