# Programmatic value change on input field is ignored by Ctrl-Z and can't be "undo"-ne

Tags: javascript, dom, undo, undo-redo

When I have an input field with a certain value in it, and some JavaScript changes its value, I used to be able to click into the field and hit Ctrl-Z in order to get the old value back.

It seems it doesn't work anymore, is that a recent update of the browsers? I am doing something wrong? Is there a way to make it work again?

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  document.getElementById("name").value = ""
}, 2000);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" value="Sylvain" />
```

Comment: I found that Chromium correctly undoes the change. At least for restoring past user input actions

Comment: @tschoppi I think you misread my question (unless I misread your comment), I'm  only talking about "programmatic" changes to the text field, not user input actions.

Comment: What I meant was: Input -> some change (like`replace`) -> More input. Only Chrome correctly handles Ctrl-Z. I found that the Mozilla and MS browsers do not go back past the change. I realize that is not quite exactly your case, and also have no solution to offer. Hence the comment and not an answer.

Comment: Oh ok I get it, thanks for the input (haha) then.

Comment: Answered here: [HTML Input - Undo history lost when setting input value programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69503315/html-input-undo-history-lost-when-setting-input-value-programmatically)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to edit a text input with javascript and add to the Undo stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027833/is-it-possible-to-edit-a-text-input-with-javascript-and-add-to-the-undo-stack)