# Change the value of a <textarea> and allow the user to undo

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, textarea, undo-redo

In the past, when you set the `value` of a `textarea` using javascript, Firefox allowed the user to undo this change (by pressing ctrl+Z, for example). However, this no longer works, and there doesn't appear to be any decent alternatives.

I've tried using `document.execCommand` to modify the `textarea`, but this requires you to select the text that you want to modify, and it doesn't appear to be possible to automatically select text in a `textarea`.

I've also heard about `document.createEvent("TextEvent")` but I can't find much information about this. It appears that you can only *insert* text at the cursor, and I need to delete text as well.

Creating my own undo/redo system and capturing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>/<kbd>Y</kbd> presses is not an acceptable solution.

Similar questions have already been asked here, but they involve only *inserting* text at the cursor, not changing the value of the textarea entirely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to edit a text input with javascript and add to the Undo stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027833/is-it-possible-to-edit-a-text-input-with-javascript-and-add-to-the-undo-stack)

Comment: @fregante No, it doesn’t the answer the question, as it uses a deprecated API.

Comment: `document.execCommand` is only deprecated on paper, there's no alternative API for this, so "deprecation" is meaningless.

Comment: ["execCommand() is now obsolete, what's the alternative?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70831583/288906)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setSelectionRange` API to manually manipulate the textarea's selection. Get the original values from `textarea.selectionStart` and `textarea.selectionEnd`.