# My jquery execCommand isn't working as i want

Tags: html, jquery, contenteditable, execcommand

I have this text editor which i created using jquery with **execCommand** and a **div** with **contenteditable** but some on it isn't working only the **undo** and **redo** is working. This is my code

```
<li data-role="bold" class="bold_str"><span><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></span></li>
<li data-role="strikeThrough" class="strike_str"><span><i class="fa fa-strikethrough"></i></span></li>
<li data-role="underline" class="underline_str"><span><i class="fa fa-underline"></i></span></li>
<li data-role="undo" class="undo_str"><span><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></span></li>
<li data-role="redo" class="redo_str"><span><i class="fa fa-redo"></i></span></li>


<div class="output_wp">
   <div class="output" id="output" contenteditable></div>
</div>


<script>
   $('li[data-role]').click(function () {
       document.execCommand($(this).data("role"), false);
    })
</script>
```

The **bold**, **strikethrough** and **underline** does not work when i highlight the text in the **contenteditable** div and click the **li button**

What do i do here cause console doesn't show any error and also whenever i click the **li** the **highlight** disappears and nothing will happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It's worth pointing out that execCommand is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), and should not be used. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581285/execcommand-is-now-obsolete-whats-the-alternative) for more current alternatives.)

`execCommand` acts on the "current editable region".  Clicking on the `li` takes focus away from the editable region, so by the time your code runs there isn't a current editable region to act on.

You can work around this by triggering the action on mousedown instead of on click, so it fires before the browser focus changes:

```js
$('li[data-role]').mousedown(function() {
  document.execCommand($(this).data("role"), false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-role="bold" class="bold_str">Bold</li>
<li data-role="strikeThrough" class="strike_str">Strikethrough</li>
<li data-role="underline" class="underline_str">Underline</li>
<li data-role="undo" class="undo_str">Undo</li>
<li data-role="redo" class="redo_str">Redo</li>


<div class="output_wp">
  <div class="output" id="output" contenteditable>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```