# How can I copy text to the clipboard with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

All Youtube tutorials seem to teach the now deprecated `Document.execCommand()`. I had a go trying it as the example goes on this MDN [website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard). Maybe there's another way?

```js
navigator.permissions.query({name: "clipboard-write"}).then(result => {
  if (result.state == "granted" || result.state == "prompt") {
    /* write to the clipboard now */
    console.log("safe");
  }
});

let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let data = "red";
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(data).then(function() {
    /* success */
      console.log("success", data);
    }, function() {
      console.log("fail")
    /* failure */
    });
});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581285/execcommand-is-now-obsolete-whats-the-alternative

Comment: Your example code works fine; just not inside an IFRAME (like StackOverflow's code snippets). I pasted it into my browser console in Chrome and had no issue. More information about when you can use the Clipboard API here: https://www.sitepoint.com/clipboard-api/

Comment: Thanks for that @JohnUleis big help

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can copy text to the clipboard just like you did in your question and also using `await/async`. Try this out below. I didn't include the query because browsers like chrome don't always return the correct permission status.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
button.onclick = async (e) => {
    let data = "red";
    try {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(data);
        console.log("all good")
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me!</button>
```