# <font> element created by document.execCommand makes highlight on text glitchy

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a contenteditable div where the user can use keyboard shortcuts in order to change the styles. To do this, I am using document.execCommand. Everything works fine, except for when I need to change the fontSize. This is because document.execCommand only does font sizes in ranges of (1-7) and not pixels. To get around this, I retroactively changed all sizes of 7 to be 14.66px (the size I need them to be). However, the fontSize command also creates a font element. The issue is that when the user also uses the highlight command with this  element in place, it glitches out the highlight and causes it to be very very short, only extending from the exact top of the text down to the bottom, instead of leaving a couple pixels of padding.

[image: The highight is very short]

Now, this I could deal with. I'm not that picky. But the issue arises when the user tries to select more text and highlight it. If the text that the user selects INCLUDES text that was apart of the  element and was already highlighted, then the previously highlighted text actually gets the padding that I was looking for, but the new text still has the very short highlight.

[image]

I'm not quite sure why this occurs and am either looking for an alternate solution that does not require me to make a  element or a way to ensure the highlighting is standarized, even when the selections overlap each other.

Here is the code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.altKey){

    if (event.code === 'Digit1') {
      //shrink//
      document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, false)
      changeFont('10px')
    }

    if (event.code === 'Digit2') {
      //remove format//
      document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, false)
      changeFont('14.66px')

  }
    if (event.code === 'Digit3'){
      //underline// 
      changeFont('14.66px')
      document.execCommand('underline', false, false)
    }

    if (event.code === 'Digit4'){
      //bold//
      document.execCommand('bold', false, false)
      changeFont('14.66px')
    }

    if (event.code === 'Digit5'){
      //highlight//
      document.execCommand('hilitecolor', false, localStorage.getItem("colorSelect"))
      changeFont('14.66px')
    }

    if (event.code === 'Digit6'){
      //highlight, bold, and underline//
      document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, false)
      document.execCommand('hilitecolor', false, localStorage.getItem("colorSelect"))
      
      var fontElements5 = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode
      changeFont('14.66px')
      fontElements5.style.fontWeight = "bold"
      fontElements5.style.textDecoration = "underline";
    }
  }
});
```

I've tried to include as much information as possible, but if you are one of the kind people who are willing to help but need more information, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bt worried that you are using the deprecated execCommand - is there a reason you definitely need it (font is also a deprecated tag).

Comment: @A Haworth I tried to look up and find alternatives to it and I couldn't find one that was simple enough for me to understand (very new, sorry). Do you have any suggestions for solutions that don't involve using it? I heard that even though it's deprecated, support probably won't be taken out as so many sites rely on it.

Comment: Having just looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581285/execcommand-is-now-obsolete-whats-the-alternative I sympathise with you.

Comment: I have look in that thread but it seems that either the solutions are way above my skill level or that they do not handle the text the same way that document.execCommand does. The only issue with my current code is that gosh darn highlight bug - I would be perfectly content using a deprecated feature if I was able to get that highlight bug fixed. I appreciate your help