# <input> text modification by renderer.js and undo in an electron app

Tags: electron

I'm working on an electron app with main.js, renderer.js and one web window.

There are some <input type="text" id="myinput"> text boxes in the main window.
If I type something manually in the text box or copy and paste some texts, I can undo input with `Ctrl + Z` or by calling `mainWindow.webContents.undo()` via IPC. That's fine.

But when I modify the text by renderer.js, something like `document.getElementById("myinput").innerText = "New input value.";`, this change is completely ignored by the electron. I can't undo this by `Ctrl + Z`, in some cases older text in the undo queue appears after the new text such like `"New input value.Older deleted text."`.

Is there a way to inform electron of these changes or is it possible to control this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript textarea undo redo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553430/javascript-textarea-undo-redo)

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027833/is-it-possible-to-edit-a-text-input-with-javascript-and-add-to-the-undo-stack

Comment: Thank you for reply. 
Yes, I checked both of them. Unfortunatelly, now it is deprecated to simulate user input by ``execCommand`` and ``initEvent``.

Comment: hm, does the deprecation warning not point to the new API?