# As of Chrome 53, how to add text as if a trusted textInput event was dispatched?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As of Chrome 53, untrusted events no longer invoke the default action. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

Before Chrome 53, this JavaScript would add an interrobang, ‽.

```
var e = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
e.initTextEvent('textInput',
                true,
                true,
                null,
                String.fromCharCode( 8253 ));
document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(e);
```

In Chrome 53, see what happens: https://jsfiddle.net/dblume/2nfhrj1j/10/

Since the event made with createEvent() is untrusted, it doesn't get its data processed by the activeElement like it did in Chrome 52 and before.

My Chrome extension stopped working as of Chrome 53 because it tried to dispatch such a textInput event. What should it do instead now?

Comment: It seems that Google is following the specifications linked from that MDN page. I'm sure this is a security measure and so I would doubt there's a simple way around it, if any. But I just don't know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Switch to `document.execCommand` that works in any text element as well as any element with `contenteditable="true"` and generates a trusted `"input"` event. The text is inserted at the caret position (replacing selection if any) just as if it was typed by a user. The only drawback compared to `TextEvent` event is that `"input"` event doesn't contain the inserted text.

```
document.execCommand('insertText', false, String.fromCharCode(8253));
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '&#8253;'); // the same
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2nfhrj1j/22/

Comment: @AlexeySh., it's a known problem in FF, but the question is specifically about Chrome.