# Access Chrome undo/redo history using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, undo, undo-redo

Is there a way to access the undo/redo history for a page or particular input box in Chrome?

My goal is to write something that will defer to Chrome's undo behavior if there's anything to undo, but to run an undo function of my own if there isn't (e.g. if I just wrote some stuff in an input box and trigger undo, it will have Chrome undo the writing of that text, if I haven't done anything to undo in the current context, then it defers to a function I have written instead).

Comment: Maybe take a look at this temp hook: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553430/javascript-textarea-undo-redo