Is there a native javascript API to manipulate the undo stack of HTML elements?
I created a contenteditable element in my page and during some events I update it by replacing the innerHTML. When I do that, the undo stack gets reset.
I found some recommendations to use the executeCommand api, but the MDN doc says it's deprecated and does not offer an alternative.

Is there a way to update the innerHTML while keeping the undo stack intact?
Alternatively, is there a way to manipulate the undo stack of an element using javascript?


@NVRM OP isn't asking why their code doesn't work (and SO shouldn't be considered a debugging service).   They're asking for concepts.  Adding executeCommand code would be irrelevant as they're looking for an alternative.  The only other "reproductible"[sic] code would be mydiv.innerHTML = newHtml;.

Counter question: What is the "undo stack" of an HTML element? AFAIK if you want a way to revert changes that you've done to an element, you have to implement that functionality yourself somehow and no HTML element ever keeps any reference to an "old state" it had.

@Davi, they are referring to the "Undo" command (Ctrl+Z) that supports undoing previous edits a user made. Once you make a change to the content via code, the user cannot undo anything anymore: the undo stack starts from scratch.

@trincot Thanks for the explanation/clarification.

I do disagree @fdomn-m. A basic reproductible code here is precious, it would be an editable div, and 2 buttons, undo and redo and the minimal boilerplate, that is to dispatch these actions into 2 functions. From here helpers passing by could try to find a quick solution for few minutes within these functions, and maybe fail. But in any case, the same potential helper passing by won't bother to rebuild all the UI just to try that.

@Davi The accepted answer there is basically to give up on using the browser's built-in undo stack and roll your own.

@Davi the question is the same as mine, thank you for linking it. The answer is also similar to the approach I had in mind if I couldn't find any way to interact with the native stack the browser hold, with the exception of listening to undo events instead of CTRL+Z. The downside is that doing it this way will not allow the user to redo, as the browser won't be made aware that an undo action took place. If you know of a way to fix that please share. Thank you!

Redo an undo is just extending the history of undo so that it has a pointer in the stack/list.   When a change is made, discard all after the pointer and add the change.  When undo is actioned, move the pointer back/down the stack and apply the value, without changing the stack - when redo is action, move the pointer along/up the stack and apply the value.

Possible alternative https://stackoverflow.com/a/7554295/2181514 (unclear if it works with a contenteditable)
